# My instance variable isn't holding its value

Tags: ruby, instance-variables

Okay, so I'm building something that takes a text file and breaks it up into multiple sections that are further divided into entries, and then puts `<a>` tags around part of each entry. I have an instance variable, `@section_name`, that I need to use in making the link. The problem is, `@section_name` seems to lose its value if I look at it wrong. Some code:

```
def find_entries
  @sections.each do |section|
    @entries = section.to_s.shatter(/(some) RegEx/)
    @section_name = $1.to_s
    puts @section_name
    add_links
  end
end

def add_links
  puts "looking for #{@section_name} in #{@section_hash}"
  section_link = @section_hash.fetch(@section_name)
end
```

If I comment out the call to `add_links`, it spits out the names of all the sections, but if I include it, I just get:

```
looking for  in {"contents" => "of", "the" => "hash"}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: show us the regex you used.

Comment: do a `puts $1.to_s` and show us the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$1` is a global variable which can be used in later code.`$n` contains the `n-th (...)` capture of the last match

```
"foobar".sub(/foo(.*)/, '\1\1')
 puts "The matching word was #{$1}" #=> The matching word was bar

"123 456 789" =~ /(\d\d)(\d)/
 p [$1, $2] #=> ["12", "3"]
```

So I think `@entries = section.to_s.shatter(/(some) RegEx/)` line is not doing match properly. thus your first matched group contains nothing. so `$1` prints nil.

Comment: Thanks much! You're right, the RegEx was returning a blank value first, which was causing all the problems. It looks like just adding "if @section_name != """ will solve this problem. Cheers!